# Is Postgres appropriate for this application? (1 billion inserts a year)

Tags: postgresql, scalability

I am currently working on drug record management system which needs to record and retain insurance billing information for patients. So far, all the typical information (patient profile, prescriber profile, drug information etc.) can easily be handled by a single postgres server as they don't really scale past the tens of millions of rows, but I am worried about the billing information as that enters into the billions territory.

Some back of the napkin calculation:
Each location (~2000) performs about 300 billing transactions a day - this translates to about 1000 inserts. So this is about 2000 * 1000 * 365 = ~700 million inserts a year.

There will also be a migration of historic billing data which goes back about a decade so thats another 7 billions records thats already there. Since this is medical information **we're not allowed to delete any of it** including all the new insertions moving forward.

Each billing row has a patient id, billing number, date and other insurance related information. So this table only needs to support three types of look ups:

1. Finding all the billing rows for a particular patient
2. Finding all the billing rows for a particular number
3. Finding all the rows within a certain time period

Is postgres appropriate for this type of workload?

Comment: There's not really such a thing as choosing a database system based on amount of data, all modern database systems perform *roughly* the same for the same use cases. Can PostgreSQL handle querying Tables that hold 10s of billions of records?...absolutely. But the performance will depend on how much data you plan to query at one time. It's actually rarely a matter of how big the Table itself is, but more so how much data you want to read from the Table at any given time. What's the most amount of rows (approximately speaking) that any of your use cases could pull back at one time?

Comment: Just because you need to keep historical records doesn't mean they need to be stored in the same table (or even the same database) as the active data.